# Getting error datetime.date(2018, 6, 12) is not JSON serializable in Python

Tags: python, json, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I am trying to use Flask-Ask and create an Alexa skill. I am getting issue while storing date and time into json

Below is the error

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.date(2018, 6, 12) is not JSON serializable
```

Below is the code snippet

```
@ask.intent("BookDateConfirmIntent")
def booking_confirmed(confirm_date):

    start_date = session['attributes']['startDate']
    data = {'services': '1234a', 'startDate': start_date, 'message': 'booking confirmed'}
    print json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

The date being passed is like 2018-06-12

I read that we need to serialize this and I am not able to get it working correctly for the above code requirement. Someone please help. Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure `start_date` is a string, not a `datetime` object.

Comment: Is this helpful : https://code-maven.com/serialize-datetime-object-as-json-in-python

Comment: @NikhilWagh Thanks I read this, but I am not taking the present datetime. I am passing date and time which is unique like for doing appointment. Can you please change the above code accordingly which will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can try type-casting the `datetime` `object` to `string`.

Change `start_date` to `str(start_date)`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you're taking present datetime or some in particular. What matters is the `type(start_date)` is `datetime.date`.

You can try something like this:

```
def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.date):
        return "{}-{}-{}".format(o.year, o.month, o.day)

def booking_confirmed(confirm_date):

    start_date = myconverter(session['attributes']['startDate'])
    data = {'services': '1234a', 'startDate': start_date, 'message': 'booking confirmed'}
    print json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

Comment: what is  `type(session['attributes']['startDate'])`?

Comment: I have imported it from the flask_ask framework `from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session`

Comment: what does this print for you? `print type(session['attributes']['startDate'])`

Comment: '<type 'str'>' I fixed this problem by converting to string.. but this `session.attributes = save_booking_date(BookingDate)` overwrites the existing attribute. Can you please tell me how to append the attributes in session ?

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you're trying to do. What does `save_booking_date(BookingDate)` returns. And if you don't want to it to overwrite create a new `key` (It's a dictionary). Or else just append it `+=`.